# Failed to start data node in Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-manager

I am trying to installing CDH 4.6 in my cluster which is of 3 nodes.
One data node out of this 3 is not able to start at all.
Tried searching and solving this by all possible ways, but failed.
Please help me in solving this.
Below is the log.

```
5:49:10.708 PM  FATAL   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode 
Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: the path component: '/' is world-writable.  Its permissions are 0777.  Please fix this or select a different socket path.
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocket.validateSocketPathSecurity0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocket.bindAndListen(DomainSocket.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.net.DomainPeerServer.<init>(DomainPeerServer.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.getDomainPeerServer(DataNode.java:603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initDataXceiver(DataNode.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1925)
5:49:10.723 PM  INFO    org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil 
Exiting with status 1
5:49:10.725 PM  INFO    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode 
SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at xx.xx.xxx.xxxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you confirmed that your root filesystem is not set to 777 permissions?

This should be the correct permissions for root(/):

```
[root@server ~]# ls -Ald /
dr-xr-xr-x. 29 root root 4096 Feb 20 13:53 /
```

If you see this, then your root filesystems need to be chmod 555:

```
[root@server ~]# ls -Ald /
drwxrwxrwx. 29 root root 4096 Feb 20 13:53 /
```

Comment: my root has this permission.   drwxrwxrwx. 30 root root 4096 Mar 10 10:31 /

Comment: I changed it to 755 its working now. Thanks for showing me a way.

Answer (score 0):

Changing permission to 755 of root filesystem will resolve issue